# How to add text on special offers page opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: php

I want to add text on Special offers page  `.../index.php?route=product/special` in opencart 1.5.6.4 but not sure which code to add and where exactly. It's 2 possible route where to add code:

`catalog\controller\product\special.php`

and

`/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/specials.tpl`

I also want to add meta title and meta description on that page.

Any help will be very appreciated because cannot find any module to fix that or anyone who achieved that in OC 1.5.6.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's 100% working for you.

Find the Controller Path of the Page. You wish to edit and then do the below,

**PATH : catalog\controller\product\special.php**

**Find:**

```
$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
```

**Add After:**

```
$this->document->setDescription('My description, this is where i type my text after i remove this text.');
$this->document->setKeywords('my, keyword, this, is, the place, holder, for, my, keywords');
```